# Лицензия при использовании шрифтов для captcha

Tags: шрифты

Имеется платный шрифт. Предположим, имеется лицензия на его использование в личных целях (на одну рабочую машину, к примеру). Могу ли я использовать его на сервере для генерации капчи? Если нет, то почему и какую лицензию мне тогда необходимо приобретать?

Comment: всё зависит от лицензии, да и зачем вам проприетарный шрифт в капче ?

Comment: В том то и дело. Какая это будет лицензия то? Никто толком не знает. Вот если встроить шрифт в css, то лицензия как раз понятна. Ну можно не только для капчи, например для вывода картинок с текстом данного шрифта.